# Windows Phone 7 Log In Error with Isolated Storage c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, authentication

Hi I currently have a log in screen on the main page that lets the user type in their username and password to log in and a registration page for the user to register their username and password with the system when their log in is incorrect. I want it so that when the user tries to log in on the main page the program tells the user that their username and password isn't recognised to which they have to go to the registration page and register first. Right now that only works if the user enters blank spaces in the username and password box but whenever they put text in the system crashes.

When the user navigates to the registration page and types in their username and password and registers successfully the program tells them they have registered successfully and then they proceed back to the home page to log in to which they can log in fine but for some reason the system crashes whenever the user tries to log in when they type in the username or password on the main page without registering. How can I do it so that when the user tries to log in with a username and password before registering the program says that their username and password cannot be recognised?

Here is my code for the main page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace TimeSheetRecordingSystem
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            //textBox2.Text = "";
        }

        public class UserInformation
        {
            string username;
            string password;

            public string Username
            {
                get { return username; }
                set { username = value; }
            }

            public string Password
            {
                get { return password; }
                set { password = value; }
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordBox1.Password))
            {
                XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("People.xml", FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<UserInformation>));
                        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                        {
                            List<UserInformation> users = (List<UserInformation>)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/timesheet.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        }
                    }
                }

                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("People.xml", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<UserInformation>));
                        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                        {                            
                           serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, GeneratePersonData());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            else if (textBox1.Text == "" || passwordBox1.Password == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is not recognised");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/registration.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

        private List<UserInformation> GeneratePersonData()
        {
            List<UserInformation> data = new List<UserInformation>();
            UserInformation ui = new UserInformation();
            ui.Username = textBox1.Text;
            ui.Password = passwordBox1.Password;
            data.Add(ui);
            return data;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my code for the registration page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


    namespace TimeSheetRecordingSystem
{
    public partial class registration : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public registration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = "";    
        }

        public class UserInformation
        {
            string username;
            string password;

            public string Username
            {
                get { return username; }
                set { username = value; }
            }

            public string Password
            {
                get { return password; }
                set { password = value; }
            }



        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordBox1.Password))
            {

                ////Write to Isolated Storage
                XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("People.xml", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<UserInformation>));
                        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                        {
                            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, GeneratePersonData());
                            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/account successful.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "" || passwordBox1.Password == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is not recognised");
            }

        }

        private void saveText(string filename, string text)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isif = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream rawStream = isif.CreateFile(filename))
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(rawStream);
                    writer.Write(text);
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private List<UserInformation> GeneratePersonData()
        {
            List<UserInformation> data = new List<UserInformation>();
            UserInformation ui = new UserInformation();
            ui.Username = textBox1.Text;
            ui.Password = passwordBox1.Password;
            data.Add(ui);
            return data;
        }              
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: I suggest you modify your questions to be about a specific error/problem and point it in your code and remove the extra code.

Comment: I cannot understand your code. You are writing it to isolated storage on registering. But in the main page how are you comparing man?It definitely throws an error when it doesn't find that object right? So i ask you to rewrite your main page code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system will have just one user at a time, why don't you use **Isolated Storage Application Settings**.

You could do something like this on **Login page**:

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

private void loginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("email") && IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("password"))
    {
        if((CType(appSettings("email"),String) == txtEmail.Text) && (CType(appSettings("password"),String) == txtPassword.Text)
        {
            //Successful Login
        }
        else
        {
            //Redirect to registration page
        }
    }
    else //This means he is a first time user as settings have not been stored even once yet
    {
        //Redirect to registration page
    }       
}
```

On **Registration page** you could do this:

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
appSettings.Add("email", txtEmail.Text.ToString());
appSettings.Add("password", txtPassword.Text.ToString());
```

Try this out. I haven't tested it by running it, but this should definitely work. Do let me know.